# When to use '.flat', '.flatiter' or '.flatten()'

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

When is it appropriate to use which of the three flattening arguments '.flat'/'.flatiter'/'.flatten'? I know that '.flat' returns a 1D iterator over an array, does this mean that the array is left in the original shape and each element in the array can be accessed with a single index (for example using a single for loop even though the array may be highly dimensional). And '.flatten' returns a complete copy of the original array flattened out into a 1D array.

Which is less resource intensive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`flatiter` is just the type of the iterator object returned by `flat` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html)). So all you need to know about it is that it's an iterator like any other.

Obviously, `flatten` consumes more memory and cpu, as it creates a new array, while `flat` only creates the iterator object, which is super fast.

If all you need is to iterate over the array, in a flat manner, use `flat`.

If you need an actual flat array (for purposes other than just explicitly iterating over it), use `flatten`.

Comment: And `ravel` - a view.  Think `flatten` without the copy.

Comment: And don't forget `reshape(-1)`.