# Numpy.array reshape from multiple brackets to 2 brackets

Tags: python, numpy

I have same data which I need in a one-dimensional numpy.array, but for some reason I don't get them in the right format. My biggest problem is that I don't really know what to look for.

My data is in a form like this:

```
yTrue

    [[27.23]
     [26.38]
     [26.19]
     [26.21]
     [26.24]
     [27.47]
     [37.85]
     [53.35]]
```

but in order to calculate it I need my data to be stored as a one-dimensional array, if I'm right, so they have to look like this:

```
Ypred

    [26.63003973 26.34320268 26.05945521 25.77876403 25.50109623 25.22641923]
```

`type()` tells me that both variables are the same `class:<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: The shape of the first is (8,1). Check it out. You can use `reshape` or `ravel` to get a (8,) shaped array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `.flat` attribute of your array. If that isn't quite what you're looking for, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523123/when-to-use-flat-flatiter-or-flatten) for other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have a (n,1) shape array, like:

```
In [39]: arr = np.random.rand(5,1)*100                                          
In [40]: arr                                                                    
Out[40]: 
array([[39.12922352],
       [66.79745338],
       [51.97361542],
       [97.60386022],
       [85.89486218]])
```

there are many ways to reshape it to (n,), 1d:

```
In [41]: arr.ravel()                                                            
Out[41]: array([39.12922352, 66.79745338, 51.97361542, 97.60386022, 85.89486218])
In [42]: arr.reshape(5)                                                         
Out[42]: array([39.12922352, 66.79745338, 51.97361542, 97.60386022, 85.89486218])
In [43]: arr.reshape(-1)                                                        
Out[43]: array([39.12922352, 66.79745338, 51.97361542, 97.60386022, 85.89486218])
In [44]: arr.flatten()                                                          
Out[44]: array([39.12922352, 66.79745338, 51.97361542, 97.60386022, 85.89486218])
In [45]: arr[:,0]                                                               
Out[45]: array([39.12922352, 66.79745338, 51.97361542, 97.60386022, 85.89486218])
```

Take your pick, read their docs, experiment.

What you show is the `str` representation:

```
In [46]: print(arr)                                                             
[[39.12922352]
 [66.79745338]
 [51.97361542]
 [97.60386022]
 [85.89486218]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It worked out. My real problem was that i didnt understand the differences of the arays in that moment. 
Thanks